# php json decode result in another json decode

Tags: php, json

I have 2 json data from `nosql`. first match if the search word match in `$array1`, get the `item number` then put `item number` into `$array2`, get the price of custom search require. But my code cause `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` in 
`foreach($json2[$num] as $data2)`

```
$str = 'paper';
$array1 = '[{"a":"1","b":"book"},{"a":"2","b":"paper"}]';  
$array2 = '[{"1":["17.00","22.00"]},{"2",["4.50","6.00"]}]';
$json1 = json_decode($array1);
$json2 = json_decode($array2,true);
foreach($json1 as $data1){
    if(preg_match('#'.$data1->b.'#',$str,$match)){
        $num = $data1->a; // $num = 2
    }
}
foreach($json2[$num] as $data2){
    foreach($data2 as $newdata){
        echo $newdata.'<br />'; // 4.50, 6.00
    }
}
```

Comment: That error means that `$json2[$num]` is null or not defined. Try debugging with `var_dump`.

Comment: @Tom van der Woerdt, get back: `array(2) { [0]=> array(1) { [1]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(5) "17.00" [1]=> string(5) "22.00" } } [1]=> array(1) { [2]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(5) "4.50" [1]=> string(5) "6.00" } } }`

Comment: that looks like a dump of your `$json2` variable, but what about `$num` and `$json2[$num]` ?

Comment: @Tom van der Woerdt, it is the result from the first foreach `$num = $data1->a`

Comment: Sure, but it's always a good idea to check the actual contents of the variable when something goes wrong.

Comment: `'[{"1":["17.00","22.00"]},{"2",["4.50","6.00"]}]'` is not valid JSON.  It should be `'[{"1":["17.00","22.00"]},{"2":["4.50","6.00"]}]'` (`:` after `"2"` not a `,`).

Comment: @Rocket, thanks for your notice, I corrected it, but then...

Comment: @Rocket, how to find the data wicth is  `{"2":["4.50","6.00"]}` from 2ed foreach? number "2", is from the check in 1st foreach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off your JSON for `$array2` is not valid.  It should be:

```
[{"1":["17.00","22.00"]},{"2":["4.50","6.00"]}]
-----------------------------^
This should be a ":", not a ","
```

Your JSON is actually an array of objects (arrays).  `var_dump($json2);` shows this.

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [1]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(5) "17.00"
      [1]=>
      string(5) "22.00"
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [2]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(4) "4.50"
      [1]=>
      string(4) "6.00"
    }
  }
}
```

You're gonna need to loop over it like this:

```
foreach($json2 as $data2){
    if(array_key_exists($num, $data2)){
      $data2 = $data2[$num];
      foreach($data2 as $newdata){
          echo $newdata.'<br />'; // 4.50, 6.00
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `$num = 2` in your comments is correct, you'll be accessing the third element in `$json2` but you can't since there only are two.

**Update**
Oops, how did I miss this? Your `$array2` already has the indices right there, you're just not loading them properly. You can simply loop through `$array2` and look for the key. However, a better solution would be to load the data properly, by filling `$array2` as a dictionary rather than a list.

Comment: so how to do in my second foreach? I need preg_match get the `item number` form `foreach 1` , then use the number get the `data` from  `foreach 2`.

Comment: I suppose you could use `$json2[$num-1]` but I'm unsure whether that's a temporary fix or whether that's the actual solution for your problem.

Comment: `$json2[$num-1]` is not a good solution, these data stored in my `nosql`, I will always update my data, maybe the stored order will be changes in the future, maybe next time, `$array2 = '[{"2",["4.50","6.00"]},{"1":["17.00","22.00"]}]';` so the result will wrong. any correct way to get the result as I need? Thanks.

Comment: not quite know what your mean in the update, can you show some working code?(some wrong in "2", => "2": as Rocket noticed)

Comment: Won't be providing code, but you're trying to access `$num` as a key in `$json2` while it is, in fact, a value. The only way you're going to be able to access a value is by finding the key first, which means you'll have to loop through all values. A better solution would be to simply use the correct keys.